# How does a temperature sensor work?

Tags: sensor, temperature

How does a temperature sensor gather temperature? What is the mechanism used?

More specifically I want to understand how the [TMP102 sensor](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data sheet shows that it is a "diode" temperature sensor.

[image]

If you operate a diode forward biased with a known current, the voltage across it has a predictable change with temperature, about -2mV/K.

More likely they use a diode-connected transistor (which behaves more like an ideal diode) and probably operate it at two currents (alternating and typically about a decade apart) and look at the difference in voltage, which is more predictable over a wide range (but has output about 10% of the direct method, so about -200uV/K).

They also probably calibrate the temperature using EEPROM or resistor trimming at a single test temperature.

Unless they've published details of the above somewhere, they're IP of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

[image] (from p.1 in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf))

The principle is that of a diode temperature sensor, which is also called [Silicon Bandgap Temperature Sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_bandgap_temperature_sensor).  Forward voltage of a silicon diode is temperature-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of sensor uses a diode as a temperature sensor. A diode can be used as a temperature measuring device, since the forward voltage drop across the diode depends on temperature, as in a silicon bandgap temperature sensor ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Temperature_measurements)).

[image]

The value of the forward voltage is read by an analog to digital converter which makes digital data available through a serial interface.